# Proving existence and regularity of a weak solution by a standard Galerkin scheme?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am currently reading a paper on higher-order [Cahn-Hilliard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Hilliard_equation) equations:

- Laurence Cherfils, Alain Miranville, Shuiran Peng, [Higher-order anisotropic models in phase separation](https://doi.org/10.1515/anona-2016-0137), Advances in Nonlinear Analysis, March 2017.

The problem states as follows:

\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^i & \sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert =i} a_{\alpha} \mathcal{D}^{2\alpha} u - \Delta F'(u) = 0\\
\mathcal{D}^{\alpha}u &= 0 \quad \text{ on } \partial\Omega, \quad \lvert \alpha \rvert \leq k, \\
u\bigl \lvert_{t=0} &= u_0 
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
\mathcal{D}^{\alpha} = \frac{\partial^{\lvert \alpha \rvert}}{\partial_{x_1}^{k_1}\partial_{x_2}^{k_2}\partial_{x_3}^{k_3}}
\end{align}
with $\alpha = k_1+k_2+k_3 \in (\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}^3)$ and $\lvert \alpha\rvert = k_1 + k_2 +k_3$.

In this paper, they provide a few a-priori estimates:

\begin{align}
&\lVert u(t) \rVert^2_{H^k(\Omega)} \leq ce^{-c't}\bigl ( \lVert u_0 \rVert^2_{H^k(\Omega)} + \int_{\Omega} F(u_0) dx \bigr) + c'', \, \, c'>0, t \geq 0, \\
&\int_t^{t+r} \lVert (-\Delta)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \rVert^2 \,ds \leq ce^{-c't} \bigl( \lVert u_0 \rVert^2_{H^k(\Omega)} + \int_{\Omega} F(u_0) dx \bigr) + c'', \quad c'>0, t\geq 0, r>0 \text{ given },\\
&\lVert u(t) \rVert_{H^{2k}(\Omega)} \leq Q (\lVert u_0 \rVert_{H^k(\Omega)} + c', \quad c>0, t\geq 1, 
\end{align}

Now they claim, that there exists a weak solution $u$ which (if we assume that $u_0 \in H^{k}_0(\Omega)$) has regularity
\begin{align}
u \in L^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^+; H^k_0(\Omega)) \cap L^2(0,T; H^{2k}(\Omega) \cap H_0^k(\Omega))\\
\end{align}
and

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \in L^2(0,T; H^{-1}(\Omega)).
\end{align}

Regarding the proof, the authors only mention that the existence and regularity can be verified by using the above a-priori estimates and a standard Galerkin scheme.

I was trying to understand what is meant with "standard Galerkin scheme", but I wasn't very successful. Can someone please try to explain this approach to me?

Comment: [Galerkin method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerkin_method)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, how do I use the Galerkin method to prove the above regularities? I always thought that the Galerkin method is used when we want to numerically compute the solution of a PDE. We formulate a weak formulation,  chose a finite dimensional subspace, and build a discrete weak solution out of basis functions of that finite dimensional subspace.  But above, I am not (yet) interested in the discrete setting?

Comment: I am as puzzled as you are

Comment: Without thinking about Galerkin approximation at all, think about how you would show any a priori estimates of the Cahn-Hilliard equation: You would take the inner product of the equation and some solution $u$ and then manipulate it to obtain bounds. But these estimates would be "formal" in the sense that you don't yet know that a solution exists, nor do you know that you can take an inner product. The Galerkin method is a way to satisfy these issues, supposing you have an orthogonal basis to begin with. For a reference, see Chapter 7 of Evan's Partial Differential Equations textbook.